# Why server responses different HTTP redirect "Location" value using libcurl and browser?

Tags: http, libcurl

I am using libcurl to download file from server, using curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L) to follow 3xx redirection. However, the libcurl doesn't download file when HTTP redirection happens. Capturing the packet  via wiresark, I noticed that the value of "Location" is different from using browsers directly, which is the main reason why my program can't download the file. For example,the original url is "http://oldurl.com", the server's response redirect url in "Location" obtaining by libcurl is "http://redirection1.com", but which is "redirection2.com" when using the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server is probably changing the behavior based on the `User-Agent` header. You can use the curl `--user-agent` flag to set the user agent to something the site would recognize as coming from a browser to test this. [This site](http://useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) is a good resource for strings to use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and reminder. I compared the request-header between libcurl and browser and solved the problem by adding curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,1L), that is, the referer header in request message. User-Agent header is an important part, however, it is not necessary in the problem by  testing.